# How to improve drools performance?

Tags: performance, drools

Is there a way to log / monitor the time taken for rule in a Drools rule set?

Is there a way to make sure that one rule is not executed more than once(It seems to be happening in my case)

What are the general guidelines on improving Drools performance?

Currently I am using a one single DRL file with 100 odd rules.

Any additiional information you need will be provided.

Comment: What is the execution time of your rule set? Can you tell?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I was looking into some other issue, back to performance issue now. Currently it takes about 60 seconds per rule for 1000 records of main record that I am validating. This is way too high. If I bring down the ruleset to a handful of rules it it is taking 10 seconds for 1000 records. Seems like some of the rules are taking too long (DB calls are there), so I am looking into gaining some insight into what is going on in the rule set, which is taking more time, which is causing memory leaks if any etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to log/monitor rules execution, you can use either the Event Listeners, like AgendaEventListener (http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.CR1/drools-expert-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e2003) or activate Drools MBeans to monitor a Drools application using any JMX console of your choice. MBeans will give you per rule stats and summarized stats.

How to improve performance is a very broad question and the answer would be much longer than I can answer here, but the short version is: a rules engine like Drools is a relational engine similar to relational databases, but with different goals and optimizations. Nevertheless, many of the same principles apply, and you can improve performance by writing rules with tighter constraints first, sharing constraints among multiple rules and making proper use of inference/chaining.

Just FYI, if you are in the San Francisco area, we will have a free Drools bootcamp (but you still have to register) next week during the Rules Fest (http://rulesfest.org/html/home.html) where we will present many of related topics.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into enabling Drools JMX. Can you provide information on how to enable this?

Comment: Either use the knowledge base configuration MBeansOption.ENABLED, or set a system property: drools.mbeans=enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The only pitfall I found fundamental while working with drools is about when block authoring.  Don't use computations in when blocks.
This is what drools says even about **getters!**:

```
Person( age == 50 )

// this is the same as:
Person( getAge() == 50 )
```

**Note**
We recommend using property access (age) over using getters explicitly (getAge()) because of performance enhancements through field indexing. ([source](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsLanguageReferenceChapter.html#d0e7250))

[Droolsassert](https://github.com/droolsassert) testing library can help you detect rules which are triggered more than once and log/monitor time taken by each rule.